# How can i add and delete particular fields and option when i am them dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on adding input box and input box with options on selecting it from dropdown.so i am able to submit question properly, but when i am changing dropdown from input box to dropdown or vice versa then option(i.e. Rule 0) will get added for all fields as well,and when i am new rule group again option will add for all fields.I tried to add option based on index but no luck.

Attaching stackblitz for what i have done so far:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-multiple-reactive-forms-copy-wegmub?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Please suggest.Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to solve your problem.

I have added one formControl in your form called `questionType`.

```
 initPageruleGroup() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      messageType: ['', [Validators.required]],
      eligibleUsers: ['', [Validators.required]],
      questionType: ['', Validators.required],
      rules: this.formBuilder.array([this.initPageRule()]),
    });
  }
```

and added condition for Rule formarray

```
 <div
      formArrayName="rules"
      *ngIf="
        pageruleGroup
          .get('pageRuleGroupArray')
          .controls[i].get('questionType').value === 'dropdown'
      "
    >
```

You can check the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-multiple-reactive-forms-copy-k52xzm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css